# Cross selection of two columns in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table consisting of users following other users. I can query what other users a specific user (me) is following, and I can also query who are following a specific user (me). These are two lists. What I cannot query is when I have a list of people following me I need to know which one of them I am following back.

It's like Tim, Peter and Suzy are following me and I follow Tim and Suzy from the 3 of them.
This is my table: the people in the USER_ID column are following the people in the FOLLOW_ID column.

[image]

Query the list of people following me: (I am the ID ending in 26):

```
$userid = '000000000026';
    $i = 0;
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT USER_ID FROM FOLLOW WHERE FOLLOW_ID=?");

        $stmt -> execute(array($userid));
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $row2[$i] = $row['USER_ID'];
                $i++;               
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        $response["success"] = 0;
    }


        for ($c=0; $c<$i; $c++) {
            echo 'USER_ID FOLLOWING ME: ' . $row2[$c] . '<br>';
        }
```

The result:

```
USER_ID FOLLOWING ME: 000000000030
USER_ID FOLLOWING ME: 000000000033
USER_ID FOLLOWING ME: 000000000028
```

So these three people are following me as you can see from the table as well.

Now I want to know which one of these three do I follow. I don't know if getting a list of the people I am following and then matching the two lists are efficient. Based on this list I follow 4 people. I see that two of them are following me (IDs ending in 28 and 33) and I want to have this information as a result.

[image]

Desired result:

```
USER_ID FOLLOWING ME: 000000000030, NoFollow
USER_ID FOLLOWING ME: 000000000033, Follow
USER_ID FOLLOWING ME: 000000000028, Follow
```

I have only mediocre knowledge of sql so please ignore advanced techniques or provide an explanation please. Thank you.

Comment: You need a join. `SELECT f1.USER_ID FROM FOLLOW f1 JOIN FOLLOW f2 ON f2.FOLLOW_ID = f1.USER_ID AND f1.FOLLOW_ID = f2.USER_ID WHERE f1.FOLLOW_ID=?`

Comment: @scragar Sorry man I was doing the sqlfiddle and did not see your comment. You should post it as an answer as it is exactly what the OP wants. And I will delete my answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Nah, it's fine, I was posting as a comment because I wasn't confident in it and at least with a comment there's no expectation of it working. Your solution has a load of work put behind it, yours should stand as the solution.

Comment: How is '000000000026' different from '26' (or even 26)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select f1.follow_id , f2.user_id as followed_back
from follows f1 left join
      follows f2 on (f2.follow_id = f1.user_id and f1.follow_id = f2.user_id)
where f1.user_id = 1
```

This query returns `null` if the user isn't following back or it's id if the user is following back

demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb63d/3)

UPDATE:

new demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c04d99a/1). pretty much the same. if you follow back the user you get your id back. If not you get a null

```
select f1.user_id , f2.user_id as followed_back
from follows f1 left join
      follows f2 on (f2.follow_id = f1.user_id and f1.follow_id = f2.user_id)
where f1.follow_id = 1
```

Comment: Hi @JSantos. Almost, just the opposite. You retrieved those how I follow and which one of them follow me. I need those who follow me and which one of them I follow. Just to be accurate :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
select distinct t1.user_id, t1.follow_id, 
       IF (t2.user_id IS NULL, 'NoFollow', 'Follow') AS Following 
  from test t1 left join
       test t2 on (    t2.follow_id = t1.user_id 
                   and t1.follow_id = t2.user_id)
 where t1.user_id = 26
```

See it here on fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f108c/31

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. You listed those who follow me and I follow. I need everyone who is following me and I need to know if I am following them or not. Please take a look at the desired result: The first user is following me but I am not folling her, that's why the NoFollow

Comment: @JorgeCampos making it a left join, then using `IF (t2.user_id IS NULL, 'NoFollow', 'Follow') AS Following` would probably work for the change in requirements.

Comment: @scragar I was fixing it with case statemant but saw your comment and fixed it with your suggestion. Thanks.